# How to remove and replace ")" space?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have problem how to remove space between ")","(" and "/" in the sql. i just want to remove space `NOT include the text`. How to do that?.

```
For example:-
Sek. 175 (1) (a)/(b) atau Sek. 187B (1) (a)/(b)

AND i want the text to be like this:
Sek.175(1)(a)/(b) atau Sek.187B(1)(a)/(b)

This is my query:
SELECT distinct mhn.id_mohon,
'oleh sebab (' || ku.ruj_kanun || ')' ruj_kanun
  FROM mohon mhn, kod_urusan ku, mohon_ruj_luar mrl, pguna pg,
       kod_perintah kp
 WHERE mhn.id_mohon = :p_id_mohon
   AND mhn.kod_urusan = ku.kod(+)
   AND mhn.id_mohon = mrl.id_mohon(+)
   AND mrl.kod_perintah = kp.kod(+)
   AND mhn.dimasuk = pg.id_pguna(+)
   AND mhn.kod_urusan = 'PHKK'
```

Anyone know about this?

Comment: Please show us your select statement.

Comment: variable retrieving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  replace(
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
           string, 
           '\s([a-zA-Z]+($|\W))', chr(0)||'\1'
        ), 
        '((^|\W)[a-zA-Z]+)\s', '\1'||chr(0)
      ),
    '\s'),
  chr(0), ' ')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b16d/1)

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff -> Thank you very much.:)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the most effective but this should work

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(column, ' ', ''), 'atau', ' atau ')
```

Comment: I would also `TRIM` the resulting string ;-)

Comment: By the way it wouldn't handle the word `atatau` well (I don't know if it even exists or maybe it's a swear word).

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace(') (', ')(')
```

etcetera.